# Why neutrino is always left handed

Tags: mass, standard-model, neutrinos, chirality

Why all neutrinos are always left handed while all anti-neutrinos are right handed.

Comment: That is assumed in the standard model, where neutrinos don't have a mass. Since neutrino oscillation was observed, we know that neutrinos in fact do have a mass, which means they are not travelling at the speed of light. Consequently there can be a frame of reference that flips the helicity. But this hasn't been observed so far.

Comment: It's a convention.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is we don't know, there may be right handed neutrinos and left handed antineutrinos that either don't interact through the weak force or do so extremely less than neutrinos. Sterile neutrinos a theoretical candidate for these particles.